# how can i get my login page in area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 areas in my project: Admins , Members
and I have Login.csthml in view folder.
Therefor,its Address is:

> http:localhost.com:5555/Areas/Members/view/Login.cshtml

I want to create the text link "login" at home page of my site ,
when i click on it, it should go to login page that i said above.

i use this code:
@Html.Action("Login", "Members")

but , it doesnt know it should go to Members Area, and it throws an error:

> {"The view 'Login' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched:\r\n~/Views/Members/Login.aspx\r\n~/Views/Members/Login.ascx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx\r\n~/Views/Members/Login.cshtml\r\n~/Views/Members/Login.vbhtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml"}

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the area registeration on the Global.asax? When adding an area by right-clicking on the project and using the wizard all the coding for that is done automatically.

Also the address you posted is not correct... it should be something like http: localhost:[port]/[AreaName]/Members/Login

try using this url form to see if the routing is working or not

Comment: yes I have the default rout in global.ascx:

         **  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                new[] { "EshopTheme.Controllers" }
                );
        }**

Comment: I think it would be easier if you use pastebin or any other tool to put the code, or add it on the question. I would be useful seein your global.asax and your [AreaName]AreaRegistration.cs

Comment: thanks pollirrata, I found my answer by adding routeValues:
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Login", actionName: "login", controllerName: "Members",routeValues: new { Area = "Members" }, htmlAttributes: null)